# Windows CE 5.0 ignoring daylight saving time

Tags: time-zone, windows-ce

I have an embedded system running Windows CE 5.0. I am syncing time with a local NTP server.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Services\TIMESVC]
"server"=multi_sz:"192.168.19.240" 
"AutoUpdate"=dword:1
"refresh"=dword:5265c00   ; 1 day
"recoveryrefresh"=dword:493E1   ; 5m 1s
"threshold"=dword:5265C00    ; 1 day
```

The time sync works, but the problem is that windows ignores the time zone information. The clock doesn't make the change to summer time, instead is behind one hour when it should switch to DST.

The setting is "*W. Europe Standard Time*".

Unortunately, I have no system builder image.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the DST to be ignored by the device.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Clock]
"AutoDST" = dword:00000000
```